# How to run Different congestion control algorithms in FEDORA 17 ..?

Tags: fedora, linux-kernel, kernel-modules, tcp

Earlier versions of Fedora has different loadable kernel modules which includes diffrent congestion control algorithms etc at (**/lib/modules/"kernel-name"/kernel/ipv4**).These are present in the form of .ko files like **tcp_veno.ko , tcp_westwood.ko** .
 But when i started using **fedora 17** i found out that these modules are not present at the given location and i want to use different congestion control algorithms.**Please suggest me a way for using those algorithms in fedora 17. ??**

Answer (score 5):

**edit:** It appears you need to install the `kernel-modules-extra` package, which contains the congestion control algorithms.

Leaving the rest, which applies in general, regardless of distro:

They may be built-in, instead of compiled as modules. You can check which congestion control algorithms your kernel knows about:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_available_congestion_control 
cubic reno
```

There is also `tcp_allowed_congestion_control` (which ones non-privileged processes are allowed to request) and `tcp_congestion_control` (the default). Documentation is in [ip-sysctl.txt](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt).

If Fedora has not built them, you'll need to [build a custom kernel](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Building_a_custom_kernel).

Comment: You are the hero that SE needs, but not the one that it deserves.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be the case. I had already `kernel-modules` and `kernel-modules-extra` installed, but even though the /boot/config-* reports that most TCP congestion algo are compiled as a module, only tcp_dctcp is available as a module. So I can only choose between cubic, reno (kernel builtin) and dctcp (after loading the module). Other algorithms are unavailable...